# How can I destroy each button using tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

My goal is to create a game that displays a hand of cards and creates a button of each card for every round of the card game. The issue is that the program creates the buttons, but never removes them so they stack between rounds. I have tried using the destroy function on the frame and on each individual button using winfo_children. How can I ultimately clear the main frame of buttons after every round? I copied the relevant sections of my code down below. Thank you in advance.

```
class CardsFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, hand):
        Frame.__init__(self,parent, width = 14)
        self.parent = root
        for card in hand:
            self.button = Button(self, text = card, width = 14)
            self.button.pack(side=BOTTOM)
    def killCards(self,parent):
        for widget in CardsFrame.winfo_children():
            widget.destroy()

def game():
    for widget in CardsFrame.winfo_children():
            widget.destroy()
    numCards = userInput.get()
    cardButtons = Frame(root)
    CardsFrame.killCards()
    if numCards.isdigit():
        if 0 <= int(numCards) <= 52:
            hand = deal(numCards)
            result1 = str(evaluate(hand))
            cardButtons = CardsFrame(root, hand)
            cardButtons.pack()
            for cards in hand:
                print('{0:5s}{1:18s}\n'.format(' ',cards), end='')
            print('{0:5s}{1:10s}{2:5s}{3:7s}\n'.format(' ', '---------> ', 'Score: ',result1, end=''))
        result = '{0:6s}{1:3s}'.format('Score: ', result1)
        result = Label(text = 'Score: ' + result1)
        score['text'] = 'Score: ' + result1
```

Comment: You are trying to invoke various methods on the `CardsFrame` class itself, rather than on the *instance* of `CardsFrame` that you created.  Note that in order to destroy the buttons, you'd have to store that instance somewhere where it would still be available at that time - currently it's just a local variable, that will vanish at the end of the function.

Comment: You need to understand OOP concept first.